# How to turn boolean on and off in an instant when mouse clicked?

Tags: java, boolean, mouseevent

I'm working on this project and I have a boolean connected to the right mouse button, kind of. So when I press RMB the boolean switches to true, but doesn't change back to false unless I press it again. Is there a way to turn the boolean on / off in an instant? Like it stays on for 1 tick, then turns back off?
(I'm pretty fresh to Java coding, as you might understand)

vvv Code vvv

```
if(Component.isMouseRightClicked) {
    if(block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirt || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtRight || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtLeft || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtTop || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtRight || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtBottom || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtBR || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtTR || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtTL || block[x][y].id == Tile.underDirtBL) {
        if(sid != Tile.air) {
            block[x][y].id = sid;
        }
    }

    if(block[x][y].id == Tile.dirt || block[x][y].id == Tile.sand || block[x][y].id == Tile.stone) {
        if(sid == Tile.dirt) {
            block[x][y].id = Tile.dirtWall;
        }
        if(sid == Tile.stone) {
            block[x][y].id = Tile.stoneWall;
        }
        if(sid == Tile.sand) {
            block[x][y].id = Tile.sandWall;
        }
    }
}
```

That is what happens when the boolean is true

vvv The boolean being turned on (by a mouseClicked) vvv

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        Component.isMouseRightClicked = true;
    }
}
```

And here (under) is how I (miserably) tried to turn it off instantly..

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        Component.isMouseLeft = false;
        Level.blockBreakTimer = 0;
    } else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        Component.isMouseRight = false;
        Component.isMouseRightClicked = false;
        Level.buildTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

(I have buttons for other stuff as well, but I think you only need to look at the isMouseRightClicked)

Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Use a Swing Timer

Comment: the possible mistake could be using mouseclicled function, as it is called when you 'press and release' the mouse click. you should try mousepressed instead of mouseclicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, sorry. I at first misunderstood your question.

Make nested if else statements, then set MouseClicked to false at the end.

```
if(mouseRclick) {
    if(block[x][y].isUnder()) {
        if(sid != Tile.air) {
            block[x][y].id = sid;
        }
    // added "else"
    } else if(block[x][y].isGround()) {
        block[x][y].id = toWall(sid);
    }
    // Makes sure that it only runs once.
    mouseRclick = false;
}
```

(I'm on mobile right now, so I shortened it. If you want, I could retype it when I get home, but you'd have to wait an extra 30+ minutes.)